# aggregate array base on object parameter

Tags: php

I have an array of objects, each object hold two parameters, like so:

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => 'games'
        [transaction_id] => 102
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => 'media'
        [transaction_id] => 95
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => 'tv'
        [transaction_id] => 102
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => 'jane'
        [transaction_id] => 42
    )
    [4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => 'ads'
        [transaction_id] => 95
    )
 )
```

The "transaction_id" key have somtimes same values(102,95) in other objects in the array.

I want to orginizie the array so that each object with the same transaction_id value will be under a new array in the original array(Multidimensional) , like so:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
 (
  [0] => games
  [1] => tv
 )
[1] => Array
  (
 [0] => jane
  )
[2] => Array
(
 [0] => ads
 [1] => media
 )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this. It sets the array key to the value of `transaction_id`.

```
$result = [];

foreach($data as $d){
 $result[$d->transaction_id][] = $d->title;
}
```

`print_r($result);` returns,

```
Array
(
    [102] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'games'
            [1] => 'tv'
        )

    [95] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'media'
            [1] => 'ads'
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'jane'
        )

)
```

Add `$result = array_values($result);` if you want to reset the array keys to `(0,1,2)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $obj) {
    if (empty($result[$obj->transaction_id])) {
        $result[$obj->transaction_id] = array($obj->title);
    } else {
        $result[$obj->transaction_id][] = $obj->title;
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use transaction_id as a key in new array

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($oryginal_array as $row){
  if (!isset($new_array[$row['transaction_id']]))
     $new_array[$row['transaction_id']] = array();

  $new_array[$row['transaction_id']][] = $row['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach is by custom function:

```
function aggragateByProperty($inputData, $propertyName) {
    $byProperty = array();

    foreach ($inputData as $object)
    {
        $objProperties = get_object_vars($object);

        foreach ($objProperties as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($key != $propertyName)
            {
                continue;
            }

            $byProperty[$value][] = $object;
        }        
    }

    return $byProperty;
}
```

Then you can call it for any property:

```
$outputData = aggragateByProperty($inputData, 'transaction_id');
```

Sample output:

```
array(3) {
    [102]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(5) "games"
            ["transaction_id"]=>
            int(102)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(2) "tv"
            ["transaction_id"]=>
            int(102)
        }
    }
    [95]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(5) "media"
            ["transaction_id"]=>
            int(95)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(3) "ads"
            ["transaction_id"]=>
            int(95)
        }
    }
    [42]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(4) "jane"
            ["transaction_id"]=>
            int(42)
        }
    }
}
```